# C++ save & import external executable result without writing on disk

Tags: java, c++, linux, file, import

In a C++ code run in Linux, I need to call an external java executable "EXEC.JAR", make him save a result file "JAVA_RES.txt", and then import this file in C++ to parse some values.
The only way I found till now to do that is calling the system function

```
system("java -jar EXEC.JAR --input " + someInputs + " > JAVA_RES.txt");
```

The very big problem of this implementation is that writing this file on the hard disk (or in a network shared filesystem as in my case...) makes the implementation really slow (I have to call this function A LOT of times).
Is there any better way to do that? Is there a way to save the result of EXEC.JAR in the RAM memory and then import it in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can try using use popen() this way:

```
int main(void) {
        FILE *in;
        extern FILE *popen();
        char buff[512];
        char s[1024]; //someInput
        if(!(in = popen("java -jar EXEC.JAR --input " + s, "r"))){
            exit(1);
        }

        while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
            printf("%s", buff);
        }
        pclose(in);
    }
```